# How do you schedule a task using schtasks.exe through an installer without receiving an "Access Denied" message?

Tags: inno-setup, windows-task-scheduler

I am creating an installer for a Windows application that will be run daily at midnight. I am attempting to schedule the task by running the following command after all files have been installed:

```
schtasks.exe /create /tn "My Task Name" /xml "path/to/file.xml"
```

However, no task was created when I ran the installer. I opened command prompt and tried typing in the command manually to see what went wrong, and the only output I received was `ERROR: Access is denied.` I followed the suggestions of others and added the `/ru` switch, but even after entering the correct password, I still received the access denied error message. I found [this answer,](https://serverfault.com/a/37099) which involved modifying the registry using a program called SubInACL, which might work, but would probably be a bad idea, since this would have to be installed and run on all end users' machines just so that the task can be scheduled in the first place. Is there any other way to schedule a task through the command line, or will I have to use something other than Task Scheduler?

Comment: Task scheduler needs admin rights to create a task and I can imagine you forgot to elevate your command prompt when trying to find the failure (hence the *Access denied* error). If so, elevate the command prompt to inspect the problem next time. But to your setup, is your setup running with adming rights ? If so, you could try to run your command line from `[Code]` section and inspect the error code returned by the `schtasks.exe`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. My setup does run with admin rights, so I moved it to the [Code] section, and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My advice was about to examine the problem, but well, if that helped :) You're welcome! And feel free to post and accept your own answer with a solution that you've used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was that running schtasks.exe from the `[Run]` section caused it not to be elevated to the Administrator level. I used the `Exec()` function in the `[Code]` section, and that made it run with Administrator privileges, which solved the problem.